# I need to build author pages from Contentful in React

Tags: reactjs, contentful

my group is doing a project where we need to make a blog in Contentful

My task was to 
add an avatar/image
add content (bio etc.)
import to react + create pages for all authors - on the authors pages of contenful.

I tried pulling the contenful API to react via

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker'
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import * as contentful from 'contentful'
import App from './App'
import './index.css'

var client = contentful.createClient({
space: '2qe6xgfwyxeo',
accessToken: 'EQmQpy9QiQVaI9N-fTWhdUwTfX_hbT2vhagtvr5j1u8' })

client.getEntries().then(entries => {
    entries.items.forEach(entry => {
      if(entry.fields) {
        console.log(entry.fields)
      }
    })
  })

  ReactDOM.render((
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  ), document.getElementById('root'))
  registerServiceWorker()
```

But it doesn't come up on my console log / I am not sure how to add author pages to this.

Does anyone have any advice on this topic?

Comment: I would advise you to research how to use react to retrieve data instead of a using promise/call back to try to insert data.

Comment: If your console is logging nothing you also might want to add a catch handler to see what going on. :)